# Getting "xxx.storyboard is currently locked because it is a remote resource" in storyboard preview xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, preview

In `xcode (7.3.1) storyboard` , when we click the assistant editor and select the `preview` of the story board, we get the output of the storyboard design. 
There is a lock button at the top, when I click that, it is getting `xxx.stroryboard is currently locked because it is a remote resource` and could not unlock.
Also I had other questions..
 1) I could add options like `iphone 4.4,4.7,3.5 inches`, but I could not remove those after I added. How to remove those added?
2) I could not move the preview screen to view it and zoom it because there are no horizontal and vertical scroll bars.How could I scroll it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lock` is not an issue for you!

Second thing you can select any preview and press `delete key` from keyboard to remove it! and you can't scroll horizontally in assistant editor preview. You can scroll vertically by `scroller` of your `mouse` even though scroll bar is not visible!

Comment: Thanks @Lion, Got it